# Handle non-submit input types in django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, ajax

Okay so I have two input tags with types as buttons.

```
<div class="buttons-for-trade-or-sell" style="display: flex; position:relative;left: 33px; top:14px">
<div class="button-to-trade">
    <input type="button" class="trade-btn" id="button-to-select-trade" name="trade1" value="Trade"></input>
</div>
<div class="button-to-sell">
    <input type="button" class="sell-btn" id="button-to-select-sell" name= "trade2" value="Sell"></input>
</div>
```

My problem is how do I send to the server side code which button is selected. For example, if the trade-btn is selected i want the boolean to be set to true in my view. Then from there I would handle it accordingly. Basically, how do I send which button is selected to the server-side?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this. One of them is to use pure `javascript` and embed a hidden `form_type` in the `form` which specifies whether the form is `trade` or `sell` and assign each button to the function with different input parameter.

```html
<from id="my_form" action="#" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input id='form_type' name='form_type' value='' class='d-none' style='display: None;'>
  <div class="buttons-for-trade-or-sell" style="display: flex; position:relative;left: 33px; top:14px">
  <div class="button-to-trade">
      <input type="button" onclick="update_value_and_submit('trade');" class="trade-btn" id="button-to-select-trade" name="trade1" value="Trade"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="button-to-sell">
      <input type="button" onclick="update_value_and_submit('sell');" class="sell-btn" id="button-to-select-sell" name= "trade2" value="Sell"></input>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
function update_value_and_submit(val){
  let ftype = document.getElementById('form_type');
  ftype.value = val;

  let my_form = document.getElementById('my_form');
  my_form.submit();
}
</script>
```